# Screenshot of Mainform shows subform. How to make sure subform is closed?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I want to make a screenshot of a Panel on my Mainform. This screenshot should be made after the user chose some Options on a subform. At the beginning everything went fine but now the screenshot contains parts of the subform.

The subform gets opened like this:

```
private void Bexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //button
{
    ex = new Export();
    initexForm();
    ex.FormClosed += this.exFormClosed;
    ex.TXTfilename.Focus();
    ex.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

The function which makes the screenshot:

```
void exFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = Mainpanel.Bounds;
        bounds.Width = bounds.Width - 6;
        bounds.Height = bounds.Height - 4;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(
                         Mainpanel.PointToScreen(new Point()).X + 3,
                         Mainpanel.PointToScreen(new Point()).Y + 2, 0,
                         0, bounds.Size);
            }

            bitmap.Save(Application.StartupPath + temppic.bmp);
            Document doc = new Document();
            ...
```

I used the events `FormClosed` and `FormClosing`, both with similar results. Then I tried to hide the subform with `ex.Hide()` but it  hid the whole program, means the screenshot showed the desktop from behind the program.

Anybody an idea how to make sure that the subform is closed before making the screenshot?

Jonathan

Comment: Call ex.Hide() and then this.Show()

Comment: tried that already ... screenshot showed the visual studio behind my program :/

Comment: Do the Export-form change the mainform in any way (the code for Export is not included but if it's just filename etc)? If it is just filename and options you could just take a screenshot before opening it and keep it in memory until after :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be that the main form didn't have time to repaint after the subform closed.

```
this.Update();
```

will force the Form to repaint (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create a dummy form that's the size of the control you want to draw then add the control to the dummy form and show the form and draw the control from the dummy.

```
public Bitmap ControlToBitmap(Control ctrl)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(ctrl.Width, ctrl.Height);
    //Create form
    Form f = new Form();
    //add control to the form
    f.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    //set the size of the form to the size of the control
    f.Size = ctrl.Size;
    //draw the control to the bitmap
    ctrl.DrawToBitmap(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, ctrl.Width, ctrl.Height));
    //dispose the form
    f.Dispose();
    return image;
}
```

So if you call it like this:

```
void exFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bitmap ControlToBitmap(Mainpanel);
    bitmap.Save(Application.StartupPath + temppic.bmp);
    Document doc = new Document();
    ...
```

This will work even if the form has already been closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
void exFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = Mainpanel.Bounds;
        bounds.Width = bounds.Width - 6;
        bounds.Height = bounds.Height - 4;
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(
                            Mainpanel.PointToScreen(new Point()).X + 3,
                            Mainpanel.PointToScreen(new Point()).Y + 2,
                            0, 0, bounds.Size);
            }
```

...